# Proving a complex statement is true for all natural numbers

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

> Prove that the following is true for all natural numbers:
>   [image]

Trying to simplify with known equivalences: applying De Morgan on the red part and $p\to q\equiv \neg p \vee q$ on all parts:

$\forall p(\color{red}{\exists a,b((p\mid ab)\wedge(p\not \mid a)\wedge(p\not\mid b))}\vee\color{blue}{(\forall d(d\not\mid p)\vee(d=p)\vee(d=1)) })$

For the red part if $p=10 $: $10\mid 10 \wedge 10\not \mid 5\wedge 10 \not \mid 2$, so it's true, although not sure if for all $p$.

The blue part is a contradiction since for example $2 \mid 6 \vee 2\neq 6 \vee 2\neq 1$.

Does simplifying it the right way? Is it enough to show the red part always true?

Comment: The statements says: for all $p$ we have that ($p$ is [prime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_element) or $1$) implies ($p$ is [irreducible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreducible_element)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If for any a and b, p|ab => p|a or p|b, then p is prime. Of course:

Assume p isn't prime. Then, there are u and v, with 1 < u < p and 1 < v < p, such that p = uv. But p divides itself, so p|uv, but by initial assumption this means that p|u or p|v, which implies that p is less than or equal to u or less than or equal to v, which is impossible.

Now that p is prime, let d be any natural number. If d divides p, then it's either 1 or p because the divisors of a prime number are either 1 or itself.